# xpath search php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i keep getting the following error messages

```
Notice: Undefined index: txtSearch in     /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/searchprocess.php on line 11

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Invalid expression in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/searchprocess.php on line 22

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/searchprocess.php on line 22

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/searchprocess.php on line 26
Title
```

then i try to run my search file

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

$header = makeHeader();


// create an instance
$holidayDoc =         simplexml_load_file('http://numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w11023553/holiday/holidays.xml');      

// set $studytype to either the upper case request or null
$txtSearch = $_GET["txtSearch"];

// set the query using the studytype
if (!is_null($txtSearch)) {
    $qry = "//channel/item[description[contains(text(),\"$txtSearch\")]]";
}
else {
// blank search entered so all holidays are shown.
    $qry = "/channel/'ALL'";
}

$holidays = $holidayDoc->xpath($qry);   // do the xpath query LINE 17
// now loop through all the students
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
echo "<tr><td>Title</td></tr>\n";
foreach ($holidays as $holiday) //LINE 21
{
echo 
echo <p><strong><a href = '$link'>'$holiday'</a></strong></p>
    <p><small>$published</small></p>";

}


$footer = makeFooter();
```

?>

been fiddling with it for about 2hrs and still can't work out where i've gone wrong, any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$txtSearch = $_GET["txtSearch"];
```

with

```
if( isset( $_GET["txtSearch"] ) && ( trim( $_GET["txtSearch"] ) != '' ) ) {
    $txtSearch = $_GET["txtSearch"];
} else {
    $txtSearch = null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first warning tells you that `txtSearch` is not a value in the `$_GET`array of query string parameters. E.g. you have no `?txtSearch=something` in the url you are invoking the script with.

So you need to check how you are invoking the script. Is the querystring parameter set? Did you spell it correctly?

You could debug a bit looking at the contents of `$_GET` by doing `var_dump($_GET)`.